# Invalid regular expression issue

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regular expression for the below string

```
"+1(332)313-1231"
```

this is my regular expression

```
var regex=new RegExp('^+1([1-9]{3})+[1-9]{3}+-[1-9]{4}')
```

how can I correct the regular expression inorder to test the string with above format?

Comment: E.g., [`var regex = /^\+1\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/JqYiLB/1).

Comment: That regex wont work. You have methachar literals that need to be escaped, otherwise, they are regex group symbols `()`. Probably won't find that info in an exact duplicate that isn't ...